# Debug magento 2 codes using netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, magento-2.0

Iam using netBeans as IDE for magento coding. I have debugged simple php codes using xdebugger. While debugging it will take the path like (http://localhost/netBeans/login.phtml) in browser, ie path of code that exists(C:\wamp\www\netBeans\login.phtml).

Iam looking, is magento codes are able to debug in netBeans. The problem in netBeans is if we follow the same step as simple php program for magento, then we get 404 error in frontend. Because the url will take the path of magento code.

Actually as we know the magento frontend url format is  (http://localhost/"router_id"/"controller_name"/"action_name")

Could anyone help me on this with stepwise procedure

Comment: What is the best way to debug magento codes